# Update a table in bulk in activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to update a table in bulk passed as an array from ajax

params[:column1]= [1,2,3]
params[:column2]= ['a','b']

I have a table

```
column1 | column2 |column3
1       |  a      | true
2       |  b      | true
```

I want to first find if not available then i want to insert a record. I tried the following

```
model.where(:params[:column1] => params[:column1],
:column2 => params[:column2]).first_or_create!(:column3 => true)
```

The expected output is

```
column1 | column2 |column3
1       |  a      | true
2       |  b      | true
1       |  b      | true
2       |  a      | true
3       |  a      | true
3       |  b      | true
```

Comment: So let me get this straight: you're getting an array from AJAX of `column1` values, and another of `column2` values. You want to... what? Find an existing record, if it's there? Find it by what value? `column1`?

Comment: Find by both values using and operator.

Comment: if params is [1,2,3] and [a,b]

it should contains [[1,a],[1,b],[2,a],[2,b],[3,a],[3,b]] in the table.

there should be no duplicates with these comibinations